# angularjs - apply filter on dynamic property of object

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

what i'm trying to do is ask user to choose the property on which they want to apply filter. the data is shown in table format using ng-repeat.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SlR6E.png)

my code looks like this:
the form to add data:-

```
<form name="myform">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Name" ng-model="data.name" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email" ng-model="data.email" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <textarea class="form-control" id="comment" placeholder="Comment" ng-model="data.comment" required></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-6">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="myform.$invalid" ng-click="add(data)">Submit</button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-6">.
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="reset()" ng-disabled="myform.$invalid">Reset</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

the table to show data:-

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3" style="overflow-x:auto;">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-6"> 
                    <select ng-options="key as value for (key, value) in keys" class="form-control" ng-model="filtercolumn">
                         <option value="">Select column</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="filtertxt" placeholder="filter">
                </div>
            </div>
            <br><br>
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Sr</th>
                        <th>Date</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Email</th>
                        <th>Comment</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="x in data | filter: {filtercolumn: filtertxt}">
                        <td>{{x.sr}}</td>
                        <td>{{x.date}}</td>
                        <td>{{x.name}}</td>
                        <td>{{x.email}}</td>
                        <td>{{x.comment}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
```

and here is the controller:

```
app.controller("ctrl", ["$scope", function($scope){
    var i = 0;
    $scope.keys =  {"sr": 'Sr', "date": 'Date', "name": 'Name', "email": 'Email', "comment": 'Comment'};
    $scope.data = [];

    $scope.add = function(data){
        $scope.data.push({
            "sr": i++,
            "date": new Date().toDateString(),
            "name": data.name,
            "email": data.email,
            "comment": data.comment
        });
        $scope.data.name = "";
        $scope.data.email = "";
        $scope.data.comment = "";
    };

    $scope.reset = function(){
        $scope.data.name = "";
        $scope.data.email = "";
        $scope.data.comment = "";
    };
}]);
```

as i'm new to angular, may be i'm missing some concept.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please post your controller code - without knowing what `data` and `keys` look like it's really hard to troubleshoot. That being said, the `filter` syntax on your `ng-repeat` looks correct. My guess is you're assigning variables to `$scope` instead of using `controllerAs` and assigning variables to the controller object (see Angular Dot Rule) - that's most often what causes issues like this; you should get out of the habit of using `$scope` variables unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: @ScottByers plz have look as i have added controller code

Comment: It looks like your `data` object is empty until something is added to it ... also you're using `$scope` variables instead of controller-bound which can definitely cause problems. I recommend ditching all the `$scope` assignments and assigning the variables directly to your controller, then using `controllerAs` syntax to get a controller object to use in your HTML... then, assuming `ng-controller="myController as myCtrl"`, you'd access the variables with `myCtrl.variable`. Again your filter syntax looks fine.

Comment: i'm adding data through a form, and that adding part is working fine

Comment: Ok - so the only issue I see there, assuming the `add` function is getting called somewhere, is that you're using the `data` variable as both an array, AND an object. You push an object to it, but then reference it as an object by setting `data.name`, `data.email`, etc. to an empty string. It may be because you have `ng-model` bound that variable for your input form - so be careful not to mix your variables... use a separate (non-scope!!) variable for your form's `ng-model` directives.

Comment: can u plz look again, now added form code also

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3" style="overflow-x:auto;">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-6"> 
                    <select ng-options="key as value for (key, value) in keys" ng-change="change()" class="form-control" ng-model="filtercolumn">
                         <option value="">Select column</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <input type="Search" class="form-control" ng-init="filtercolumn= ''; filtertxt= ''" ng-model="filtertxt[filtercolumn]" placeholder="search..">
                </div>
            </div>
            <br><br>
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Sr</th>
                        <th>Date</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Email</th>
                        <th>Comment</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="x in data | filter: filtertxt">
                        <td>{{x.sr}}</td>
                        <td>{{x.date}}</td>
                        <td>{{x.name}}</td>
                        <td>{{x.email}}</td>
                        <td>{{x.comment}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
```

And here is controller:

```
app.controller("ctrl", ["$scope", function($scope){
    var i = 0;
    $scope.keys =   {"sr": 'Sr', "date": 'Date', "name": 'Name', "email": 'Email', "comment": 'Comment'};
    $scope.data = [];

    $scope.add = function(data){
        $scope.data.push({
            "sr": i++,
            "date": new Date().toDateString(),
            "name": data.name,
            "email": data.email,
            "comment": data.comment
        });
        $scope.data.name = "";
        $scope.data.email = "";
        $scope.data.comment = "";
    };
    $scope.filtercolumn = '';
    $scope.change = function() {
                        $scope.filtertxt = '';
                    };

    $scope.reset = function(){
        $scope.data.name = "";
        $scope.data.email = "";
        $scope.data.comment = "";
    };
}]);
```

This will search for input text from the selected columnName.

Comment: still not working, as i have added my controller code pls have a look

Comment: I hope i am correct on assuming what exactly you are trying to accomplish here. I am also assuming that your data part adding values correctly there. I have edited my answer. try it.

Comment: sry to dsay but after using your code, i'm getting following error: 
`**TypeError: Cannot create property 'comment' on string**`

Comment: I think that is to do with your code where yo are adding 'comment' property to the data

Answer (score 0):

So there's a couple issues with the controller code and HTML.

**First (and most important)**

Don't use `$scope` variables. Assign the variables to your controller and use `controllerAs` syntax, e.g. `ng-controller="myController as myCtrl"`. The rest of my answer is predicated on using `myCtrl` as your controller object in the HTML. Here's updated controller code using controller-assigned variables instead of `$scope` (note: I renamed your controller to myController to avoid ambiguity in `ng-controller` using `as` syntax):

```
app.controller("myController", function($scope)
{
    // need a reference to 'this' to use inside functions
    var self = this;
    var i = 0;

    self.keys =   {"sr": 'Sr', "date": 'Date', "name": 'Name', "email": 'Email', "comment": 'Comment'};
    self.data = [];

... the rest of your controller
```

**Second**

You're using the same `$scope.data` as both an Array AND an Object for your Form. This isn't easy to see because you're using `$scope` assignments. Add another input variable to your controller:

`self.formInput = {}`

Then in your form, change all your `ng-model` directives to `ng-model="myCtrl.formInput.whatever"`

**Third**

Now update your `add` function - again, assigning as a Controller variable, not `$scope`:

```
self.add = function(data)
{
    self.data.push({
        "sr": i++,
        "date": new Date().toDateString(),
        "name": self.formInput.name,
        "email": self.formInput.email,
        "comment": self.formInput.comment
    });

    // now clear the inputs on the form
    self.formInput.name = "";
    self.formInput.email = "";
    self.formInput.comment = "";
};
```

**Fourth**

Now update your HTML to use the `myCtrl` variables instead of `$scope`. So for your `ng-options` statement in the Select object:

`ng-options="key as value for (key, value) in myCtrl.keys"`

And for your repeater:

`<tr ng-repeat="x in myCtrl.data | filter: {filtercolumn: filtertxt}">`

And finally your Form's "Add" button:

`ng-click="myCtrl.add(data)"`

It's OK that your `filtercolumn` and `filtertxt` variables are accessed in the current scope since they're only used in the HTML and are automatically bound with `ng-model`. If you ever needed access to those in your controller, it'd be advisable to add them as controller variables like the new `self.formInput` variable. Personally I would do that anyway since using `ng-if`, for example, would make those model-bound variables inaccessible to the rest of the page. Just good practice to put your variables in the controller.